# How to echo or print each row of a JSON-array in Titanium?

Tags: php, json, titanium

I have a JSON array that I know is valid. The array shows all of the values when viewing in the webbrowsers:

```php
echo json_encode($response);
```

I'm thinking I can use JSON `.each();` to print these within Titanium, but I'm not sure. What I have so far, isn't working. I'm not even sure that actually puts anything on the screen even if it works.

```php
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.courseid + ' ' + val.coursename + ' ' + val.courselogo + ' ' + val.coursedesc + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: This confuses me. Why jQuery & PHP when you are in Titanium. Is it Desktop or mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Muhammad stated: use the `parse` method:

```
var jsonResult = JSON.parse(yourResponse);

for (var i = 0; i < jsonResult.length; i++) { 
  console.log(jsonResult.propertyName);
}
```